# How to distinguish "tag" and "post on wall" action in facebook API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing a facebook app. But I have the problem that the "tag" and the "post on other wall" actions both have the same format.

For example if A posts on B's wall:

```
"from": {
        "name": "A",
        "id": "123456"
     },
     "to": {
        "data": [
           {
              "name": "B",
              "id": "123456789"
           }  
        ]
     },
```

and if A tags B it comes out the same.

How I can distinguish between them ?

Comment: A is nested within "from" and B is nested within "to">"data"

Comment: It is default format of Graph API, a person who create a message is nested within from and a person who receive message is nested within "to">"data". I can't solve the problem base on it.
But,thanks for your opinion :)

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for a while today. What I ended up doing is checking if the first user in the "To" array is also contained in the "message_tags" object. If the recipient user is also a tagged user, then the current post is just a "Tag" and not a "post on other wall" as you put it.

Here is my (messy) code that does this in my application:

```
                JSONObject recipientData = story.getJSONObject("to");
                JSONArray recipientArray = recipientData.getJSONArray("data");
                JSONObject recipient = recipientArray.getJSONObject(0);
                recipientName = recipient.getString("name");
                String recipientId = recipient.getString("id");

                // if the post's recipient is also a tagged user, then this is not a post to
                // another user's wall, but rather a status update. Leave the recipient blank then.
                if(story.has("message_tags")){
                    JSONObject tags = story.getJSONObject("message_tags");
                    for(int tagIdx = 0; tagIdx < tags.names().length() ; tagIdx++){
                        JSONArray tagArray = tags.getJSONArray(tags.names().getString(tagIdx));
                        String tagId = tagArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("id");
                        if(tagId.equals(recipientId)){
                            recipientName = "";
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

For my display purposes, I set the recipientName of the post to the empty string if the post is actually just a status update with a tagged user. recipientName is only set if this is a "post on other wall."

Hope this helps someone, I know this is an old question.

Comment: Thank @mattgmg1990 . This question I posted so long so now I don't event remember what exactly it was. 1 up vote for your struggling :)

Comment: :) I posted that nearly three years ago now so I hardly remember either but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Lookout for "actions" which would only exist for wall post and not for tagged posts.

Comment: It not work @Vikas :). Becuz if i tag SO on my posts, "action" 'll be show, or my friends tag my friends, it the same :)